# What does the d do in "nmcli d wifi list ifname wlan0"

Tags: nmcli

`nmcli d wifi list ifname wlan0` - I understand that this command returns a list of avaible networks for wlan0, but what exactly does the "d" do in the command? Because "nmcli wifi list ifname wlan0" doesn't work. If someone could break this down I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means device as per --help:

```
  d[evice]        devices managed by NetworkManager
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `man nmcli` you'll get the [man page](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nmcli.html) for the tool.

I'll break it down a little for you:

```
nmcli d wifi list ifname wlan0
```

> ```
> SYNOPSIS
>        nmcli [OPTIONS...] 
>        {help | general | networking | radio | connection | device | agent | monitor}
>        [COMMAND] 
>        [ARGUMENTS...]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>       nmcli is a command-line tool for controlling NetworkManager and reporting network 
>       status...
> ```

`[OPTIONS...]` will start with a `-` or `--`.  In your case your `d` does not start with that, so the `d` is short for one of the `{...}` keywords.  In this case, the only option is `device`.  If we look at the `device` section of the man page, we see:

> ```
> DEVICE MANAGEMENT COMMANDS
>       nmcli device 
>       {status | show | set | connect | reapply | modify | disconnect | delete | monitor | wifi | lldp}
>       [ARGUMENTS...]
>
>        Show and manage network interfaces.
> ```

`wifi` in your command matches the next keyword.  There are a few entries on `wifi` including `wifi hotspot`, `wifi rescan`, `wifi connect`, but your command uses `wifi list`.  The entry on `wifi list` looks like this:

> ```
>        wifi [list [--rescan | auto | no | yes] [ifname ifname] [bssid BSSID]]
>            List available Wi-Fi access points. The ifname and bssid options can 
>            be used to list APs for a particular interface or with a specific 
>            BSSID, respectively.
> ```

So we can conclude that the command you wrote says:

- `nmcli` - I want to control NetworkManager or report network status
- `d` - I'm interested showing or managing a specific network interface (device)
- `wifi list ifname wlan0` - I want to list wifi access points visible to `wlan0`